# Managing columns with estout/esttab suite and Latex

Tags: tables, columns, spreadtab

I am using the excellent suite of tools -estout, esttab, etc.- by Ben Jann. I have a little issue by using the "esttab" ado to produce some summary statistics. Specifically, I want to show the number of observations in the middle of 2 columns (I have 4 columns in total, so would be in the middle of 2 - 2 columns). I use the 'layout' option in the following way:

```
stats(N, fmt(%18.0g) labels("\midrule Observations") layout("\multicolumn{2}{c}{@}" "\multicolumn{2}{c}{@}"))
```

Strangely, the fragment that produce this command in Latex is:

```
\midrule Observations&\multicolumn{2}{c}{314}&            &\multicolumn{2}{c}{314}&            \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&            &            &            &            \\
```

While it should only be:

```
\midrule Observations&\multicolumn{2}{c}{314}&            \multicolumn{2}{c}{314}            \\
```

Could anybody help me with the use of the "layout" option in esttab/estout? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Can you add a MWE?

Comment: Hi @samcarter, will post the MWE soon.  As it involves a Stata do-file, I need to work on it a bit.